# How can you debug a TON smart contract in FunC and print logs or dump variables?

Tags: ton

I'm developing a smart contract for TON blockchain in FunC and I'm trying to find a bug in my code. I'm trying to debug the issue and will appreciate something like `console.log()` from JavaScript so I can add prints / logs in strategic places and understand what's going on. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TVM has a special function for [dumping variables](https://ton.org/docs/#/func/builtins?id=dump-variable) in debug - `~dump`

Run `~dump(variable_name);` to print a variable's contents.

Run `~dump(12345);` to print the number `12345`.

Example:

```
() recv_internal(int msg_value, cell in_msg, slice in_msg_body) impure {

  ;; let's say I want to print the value of the variable msg_value
  
  ~dump(msg_value);
}
```

Please note that this command will not run on mainnet, so do not deploy production contracts with it. My favorite way to test smart contracts locally is using [ton-contract-executor](https://github.com/Naltox/ton-contract-executor) - this awesome library run a local version of the TVM in web-assembly right inside Node.js, which is very convenient for writing JavaScript/TypeScript tests.

To enable debug prints in ton-contract-executor, when you create your contract instance pass `debug: true` in SmartContractConfig and print the logs after interacting with the contract:

```js
import { SmartContract } from "ton-contract-executor";

const contract = await SmartContract.fromCell(codeCell, dataCell, {
  debug: true // enable debug
});

const send = await contract.sendInternalMessage(...);

console.log(send.logs); // print the logs
```

Answer (score 0):

For debugging real transaction in network, you can use [this guide](https://github.com/disintar/toncli/blob/master/docs/advanced/transaction_debug.md). It's pretty simple to see where something goes wrong.

Long story short:

1. Install TON binaries (soon it'll be integrated into toncli)
   You can compile it manually or donwload prebuild from GH actions (you need to be authorized) [GH actions](https://github.com/ton-blockchain/ton/actions)
2. Install `toncli` via `pip install toncli`
3. Find your transaction in [toncx](https://ton.cx/) -> [example](https://ton.cx/tx/30852564000003:KxV2c9nhQNMYyPpxQgutwQYYR5CJBckt49nTB3ayvEg=:EQDrLq-X6jKZNHAScgghh0h1iog3StK71zn8dcmrOj8jPWRA)
4. Copy logical time, transaction hash, account address (they are divided by `:`, just replace it with  )
5. Run `toncli run_transaction [-h] [--net {testnet,mainnet}] [--function FUNCTION] [--save SAVE] logical_time transaction_hash smc_address`

Working Example: `toncli run_transaction -f 0 -n testnet 3473136000005 yPJU0r+TS1X5jL6lcXEI2s0jaGHtlLw9jTlasY2QnIw= EQAox8P13VjB0hNwZmHx3fxNc82xzjtZK5G5RR9gWc6zrxfI`

Keep in mind that function selector is `0` for external messages and `-1` is for internal messages.

You will see TVM OPs (with stack dump) and exit code, gas usage. This will really help you when you'll debug transactions.

```
 execute SDEQ
 [ CS{Cell{005300000000000000008005eca15cad9dab7f1677db60c75f9ecacd1e5c5eb2990df5a6bd03d89bfca208f0} bits: 64..331; refs: 0..0} CS{Cell{00166d795f6e66742e6a736f6e} bits: 0..88; refs: 0..0} 0 -1 ] 
execute THROWIFNOT 405
 [ CS{Cell{005300000000000000008005eca15cad9dab7f1677db60c75f9ecacd1e5c5eb2990df5a6bd03d89bfca208f0} bits: 64..331; refs: 0..0} CS{Cell{00166d795f6e66742e6a736f6e} bits: 0..88; refs: 0..0} 0 ] 
execute SWAP
 [ CS{Cell{005300000000000000008005eca15cad9dab7f1677db60c75f9ecacd1e5c5eb2990df5a6bd03d89bfca208f0} bits: 64..331; refs: 0..0} 0 CS{Cell{00166d795f6e66742e6a736f6e} bits: 0..88; refs: 0..0} ] 
execute LDMSGADDR
handling exception code 9: cannot load a MsgAddress
default exception handler, terminating vm with exit code 9
[ 3][t 0][2022-09-01 13:52:06.274723355][vm.cpp:558]    steps: 58 gas: used=2170, max=9223372036854775807, limit=9223372036854775807, credit=0
```